# Do I need to upgrade my ag-grid to newer version if there's any version upgrade for angular?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

If I upgrade the angular version of my project to the latest one, do I need to upgrade my ag-grid version also to the latest one to make it work? Or, my ag-grid will work without any change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, an old version will work without change.
I'm currently using version 20.2.0 with Angular 8 (the current ag-grid version is 23.1.0).

I'm not sure what will happen if you try to use an older version with Angular 9, using the Ivy Renderer. I expect that it will work ok, but I haven't tried it yet.